# Disk Partitioning using DiskPart - Virtual Disk Service Error

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, diskpart, windows-pe

I can find similar posts, but not the exact issue I am having.

I am trying to create a partition on a Dell Latitude 7490. If I run the commands below in sequence then it fails on convert gpt with the error "Disk Service Error: The object is not found". In the company we have the same make and model laptop for around 700 users. On most of these computers I am able to create partitions using disk part and on some I just can't.

sequence of commands:

```
select disk 0
clean 
convert gpt
```

To give some background I am running this when booted from Windows PE. If I I install Windows 10 from the installation media then it works and the Operating system is on there.

Can anyone help? If there is an alternate to diskpart that runs from Windows PE then I can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working now. On the Dell Latitude 7490 it seemed that I had to change the "advanced boot options"so that "Enable legacy was enabled" and "attempt legacy boot" deselected. Then the boot sequence needs to be on UEFI with Windows Boot Manger selected at the top.

After rebooting, from the F12 menu I can boot PE from the USB under legacy and then it enables me to run diskpart commands on the disk.

I think this is very specific to the model of laptop so not sure if many people will run into this.